# For Loops in VBA with the index in the variable name

Tags: vba, solidworks

I'm programming a macro for SolidWorks using VBA, and since this is more of a syntactical question, I thought I'd ask it here.

So the macro I'm writing uses 16 checkboxes, named as CheckBox1, CheckBox2, ... CheckBox16.

I tired doing this (code below) but there was an error, as the compiler said that the var name "CheckBoxi" was not defined.

```
For i = 0 To 16

    If CheckBoxi.Value Then
        'Do Something
    End If

Next For
```

Is there a way by which I can fix this, I really don't want to type out 16 such statements as the "Do Something" bit contains quite a bit of code. And by fix I mean put it in a for loop. Thanks!

Comment: Is these check boxes on a user form?

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman, I have confusion with excel!

Comment: @AlexK Since Solidworks isn't Access it is by no means obvious that this is duplicate. If the checkboxes are on a general userform then, sure, it is duplicate, but if SolidWorks allows for embedded controls then it might require an answer which addresses the particulars of the Solidworks object model.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, this is in a user form. Right, I can see why this this looks like a duplicate but I don't understand how to use the code from the suggested example and adapt it to my situation.  For example, the answer to the question posted here uses this line of code:  

    `Public Sub TextBoxNames(ByRef pfrm As Form)`

Comment: @JohnColeman Wow, I'm really struggling with formatting this comment. Anyway, I have no idea what that line of code means, and looking in the VBA Help for 'By Ref' and 'Controls' didn't yield anything useful.

Comment: Yes Solidworks is MSForms so vanilla usercontrols, there is no ole embedding in a sw document.

Comment: BradC's answer uses a `For i = 1 to 10` construct to loop controls by name, use that replacing `myForm.Controls("txt_00" & i & "_Title").Text = "hello"` with `if myForm.Controls("CheckBox" & i) then ...`

Comment: @AlexK. Is myform a placeholder name for my form?

Comment: Yes, if your actually doing this inside the form use `Me.controls`

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

`me.controls("Checkbox" & I).value`  Where Me will be the containing form.  Also, your loop starts at 0, but your post says 1.